# Laravel 5.2 | Set Custom Attribute with Calculcated Value On The Fly Never Replaced

Tags: validation, attributes, laravel-5

I've a custom validator, see below (simplified)

## Form Request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'amount' => 'required|numeric|max_invest:10000'
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'max_invest' => 'You can invest max :mi' // I want to set :mi on the fly
    ];
}
```

## Validator

```
public function validateMaxInvestment($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
{
    $this->setAttributeNames(['mi' => intval($parameters[0] - $value)]); // Try to set the attribute mi on the fly
    return $value < $parameters[0];
}
```

I did register the validator in the boot method of my service provider, like so:

```
    $this->app['validator']->extend('maxInvestment',
        'MaxInvestmentValidator@validateMaxInvestment');
```

## The problem

The validator works fine, but the message I get stays:

*You can invest max `:mi`*

Calling the method `setAttributeNames` doesn't take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a replacer for that purpose which you may miss as it is at the bottom of the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules).

> When creating a custom validation rule, you may sometimes need to
>   define custom place-holder replacements for error messages. You may do
>   so by creating a custom Validator as described above then making a
>   call to the replacer method on the Validator facade. You may do this
>   within the boot method of a service provider:

```
public function boot() {
    Validator::extend(...);
    Validator::replacer('foo', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
        return str_replace(...);
    }); 
}
```

So for your case, something like below should work.

```
protected function validateMaxInvestment($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
{
    $replace = intval($parameters[0] - $value);
    $validator->addReplacer('max_invest', function ($message) use ($replace) {
        return str_replace(':mi', $replace, $message);
    });
    return $value < $parameters[0];
}
```

Also, not sure but I guess you can also do something like below.

```
protected function validateMaxInvestment($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
{
    return $value < $parameters[0];
}

protected function replaceMaxInvestment($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
{
    $replace = intval($parameters[0] - \Input::get($attribute));
    return str_replace(':mi', $replace, $message);
}
```

Hence, probably you will need to register it again.

```
 $this->app['validator']->replacer('maxInvestment', 'MaxInvestmentValidator@replaceMaxInvestment');
```